# Smtplib returns authentication failed despite good credentials

Tags: python, django, smtp, smtplib

I use django backend to send email (but really django is irrevelant in this case), I can login via standalone client, but not via smtplib. I keep getting:

```
SMTPAuthenticationError (535, '5.7.0 authentication failed')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case It seems that the server lied it responded following string on hello request:

```
>>> conn.ehlo()
(250,
'edited.host.name Hello host.name [83.24.32.123], pleased to meet you\nENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\nPIPELINING\n8BITMIME\nSIZE\nDSN\nETRN\nAUTH GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN\nDELIVERBY\nHELP')
```

in which it annouced it supports `CRAM-MD5` authentication method, which it didn't.

Since I was in a hurry and resolving this issue with admin would end in missing the deadline, I had to patch SMTP class to prefer `PLAIN` authentication method. To do this you need to create subclass of `SMTP_SSL` and override `login` method, just copy `login` from SMTP class changing one line.

Change line that says:

```
preferred_auths = [AUTH_CRAM_MD5, AUTH_PLAIN, AUTH_LOGIN]
```

to:

```
preferred_auths = [AUTH_PLAIN, AUTH_LOGIN]
```

Anyway I posted the patched class: http://pastebin.com/ecL9A3P4.